# Should I close an S3Object?

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-java-2.0

What if I did not close the `s3object` in the `finally` clause?

Are there no resource leaks in the code below?

```
class S3ClientClass {
  lazy val amazonS3Client = this.getS3Client()
  private def getS3Client() = {
    AmazonS3ClientBuilder
      .standard()
      .withRegion(Regions.AP_NORTHEAST_1)
      .build()
  }

  def readFromS3(s3Bucket: String, filepath: String): String = {
    var s3object: S3Object = null
    try {
      s3object = amazonS3Client.getObject(s3Bucket, filepath)
      readFromS3(s3object)
    }
    finally {
      if (s3object != null) {
        s3object.close()
      }
    }
  }
 
  def readFromS3(obj: S3Object): String = {
      val reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(obj.getObjectContent))
      reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining())
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you didn't close the `S3Object`, it would lead to resource leaks.

The [`S3Object`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/S3Object.html) class should be closed to release the resources it holds, as it implements the [`Closeable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) interface; resources, in this case, would be network connection(s) to Amazon S3.

This is also explained in the [AWS Developer Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/closeable-s3objects/):

> `S3Object` contains an `S3ObjectInputStream` that lets you stream down your data over the HTTP connection from Amazon S3. Since the HTTP connection is open and waiting, it’s important to read the stream quickly after calling `getObject` and to remember to close the stream so that the HTTP connection can be released properly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In my case, should client also be closed?

Comment: The AWS SDK Java V2 examples show this logic. For example  - https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3/CopyObject.java